# How should i use the Stopwatch to calculate the download speed of files download?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In top of form1

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
```

Then

```
private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //urll.Add("http://download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip");

            label7.Text = "Downloading images";

            var v = lines.Where(s => s.Contains("Name")).Select(s => s.Substring(15));
            var q = lines.Where(s => s.Contains("Code")).Select(s => s.Substring(15));
            var r = q.Where(c => c == "is").Concat(q.Where(c => c != "is"));
            var p = v.Where(c => c == "Israel").Concat(v.Where(c => c != "Israel"));
            var n = r.Count();
            int i = 0;

            var results = p.ToList();

            downloadFile(ExtractImages.imagesUrls);
        }

        private Queue<string> _downloadUrls = new Queue<string>();

        private async void downloadFile(IEnumerable<string> urls)
        {
            foreach (var url in urls)
            {
                _downloadUrls.Enqueue(url);
            }

            await DownloadFile();
        }

        private async Task DownloadFile()
        {
            if (_downloadUrls.Any())
            {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += Completed;

                var url = _downloadUrls.Dequeue();

                await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), @"C:\Temp\TestingSatelliteImagesDownload\" + count + ".jpg");
                return;
            }
        }

        private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Calculate download speed and output it to labelSpeed.
            label3.Text = string.Format("{0} kb/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024d / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00"));
        }
```

And the completed event

```
long bytesFromCompletedFiles = 0;
        // The event that will trigger when the WebClient is completed
        private async void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Download has been canceled.");
            }
            else
            {
                ProgressBar1.Value = 100;
                count++;
                bytesFromCompletedFiles += totalBytes[count -1];
                await DownloadFile();
            }
        }
```

The problem is i never start the sw(Stopwatch) and never stop/reset it anywhere.
So in the line:

```
label3.Text = string.Format("{0} kb/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024d / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00"));
```

I see the sign of infinity on the sw

The question is where should i start/stop/reset the sw ?

Now when i'm running the program i don't see anything on label3 i guess since the infinity and that i'm not starting the sw(Stopwatch).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'd make sense to start the `Stopwatch` just before you start the download, since if you start it earlier this would yield wrong results

```
private async Task DownloadFile()
{
    if (_downloadUrls.Any())
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        [...]

        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), @"C:\Temp\TestingSatelliteImagesDownload\" + count + ".jpg");
        return;
    }
}
```

And to stop it after the download has been cancelled or is completed

```
// The event that will trigger when the WebClient is completed
private async void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if ([...])
    {
        [...]
    }
    else
    {
        [...]
    }
    sw.Stop();
}
```

Comment: you would also want to stop it before returning

Comment: @slawekwin where ? In the progresschanged event ? Could you show where else to stop it please ?